# Converting existing Integer column to primary_key type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, primary-key, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have migrated some existing tables with relations to a Rails database. I intentionally didn't allow the tables in Rails schema to have ID columns. I now want to convert one of the columns, having unique value integer data in it, to a primary_key. This is required to recreate the relationships. Is it possible? I'm asking because some other systems such as MS Access do not allow a column with existing data to be converted to AutoIncrement. Thanks.

Comment: first of all, there is no Rails Database, also what DB are you using: Postgresql, SqlLite or..?

Comment: The database is populated from the existing data by exporting the existing data to XML, adding the file to the repo, and then creating new records programmatically from the XML Nodes

Comment: you can try this (I'm not sure it's working because I don't have access to any PSQL DB): `rails db` and then: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_name)`